# List of Racket special forms

Tags: racket

Is there available anywhere, a complete list of Racket special forms (including macros provided by the standard library)? I can't find such in the documentation. (This is for use in syntax highlighting, so I'm not looking for an explanation of what each special form does, just for a compact, comprehensive list.)

Comment: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax.html

Comment: @Shawn That's a discussion of some special forms, not a list of all of them. Don't get me wrong, it's a very useful document for its intended purpose of helping programmers figure out how to use the language! It's just not useful for my particular purpose right now, of implementing syntax highlighting.

Comment: It's pretty much all the macros defined in racket/base.

Comment: @Shawn Right, but I'm looking for the full language, not just base.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)